# How to calculate the difference between two hex offsets?

Tags: hex, offset

I have been searching how to do this but I haven't find the way to do it. There's another way to calculate this difference instead of be counting one by one?

For example:

```
0x7fffffffe070 - 0x7fffffffe066 = 0x04
0x7fffffffe066 - 0x7fffffffe070  = -0x04

0x7fffffffdbe0 - 0x7fffffffda98 = ????
```

To understand these results let's suppose we open a file with an hex editor and we have the following hex numbers: 8A B7 00 00 FF, with their corresponding hex offsets: 0x7fffffffe066 0x7fffffffe067 0x7fffffffe068 0x7fffffffe069 0x7fffffffe070. The difference of the hex offsets of the numbers 8A and FF is 0x04 because they differ in 4 positions.

Comment: I didn't get the point yet.

Comment: The difference between two hex offsets is the same as the difference between two hex numbers. It's simple, basic math in base 16. What part of it specifically are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between 0x7fffffffe070 and  0x7fffffffe066 cannot be 4.

I think 0x7fffffffe070 should be 0x7fffffffe06a in your example.

Other than that I don't understand the question.
Normally you would calculate the difference with a calculator set to programmer/hexadecimal mode.

In a previous answer I explained how to calculate the number by hand, but that answer got deleted.